# Checking if an input number is an integer

Tags: bash, regular-expression, quoting, test

I'm trying to check if an input is an integer and I've gone over it a hundred times but don't see the error in this. Alas it does not work, it triggers the if statement for all inputs (numbers/letters)

```
read scale
if ! [[ "$scale" =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]
        then
            echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

I've played around with the quotes but either missed it or it did nothing. What do I do wrong? Is there an easier way to test if an input is just an INTEGER?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Remove quotes

```
if ! [[ "$scale" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
        echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash/7850641#7850641 had the quotes backwards

Comment: `if [[ $scale =~ [^0-9] ]]` is less convoluted. Doing so, puts the negation in the regular expression instead of the test condition. [**See below**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699082/39845).

Comment: A POSIX solution might be similar to [See below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574169/232326).

Answer (score 38):

Use `-eq` operator of [test](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) command:

```
read scale
if ! [ "$scale" -eq "$scale" ] 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

It not only works in `bash` but also any POSIX shell. From POSIX [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) documentation:

```
n1 -eq  n2
    True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise, false.
```

Comment: that checks if its any number, not just integers

Comment: @lonewarrior556: It works only for integer, see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. I guess you said for any number because you use new test `[[` instead of old test `[` as mine.

Comment: Good idea but a bit noisy.  I would rather not have to redirect errors to dev null.

Comment: @Wildcard: Yep, we pay it for portability.

Comment: A potential gotcha: this does *not* work if you have set the integer attribute on your variable beforehand (i.e. if the script above included `declare -i scale` before the `read` command). The problem occurs during assignment to an integer variable because any string will be interpreted as a variable name, and dereferenced (recursively). Unset or null "variable names" evaluate to 0. E.g. `unset abc; declare -i a; a=abc; # a = 0` or `a=3; b=a; c=b; declare -i d=c; # d=3`.

Answer (score 20):

As the OP seems to want only positive integers:

```
[ "$1" -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null
```

Examples:

```
$ is_positive_int(){ [ "$1" -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null && echo YES || echo no; }
$ is_positive_int word
no
$ is_positive_int 2.1
no
$ is_positive_int -3
no
$ is_positive_int 42
YES
```

Note that a single `[` test is required:

```
$ [[ "word" -eq 0 ]] && echo word equals zero || echo nope
word equals zero
$ [ "word" -eq 0 ] && echo word equals zero || echo nope
-bash: [: word: integer expression expected
nope
```

This is because dereferencing occurs with `[[`:

```
$ word=other
$ other=3                                                                                                                                                                                  
$ [[ $word -eq 3 ]] && echo word equals other equals 3
word equals other equals 3
```

Comment: Note that in bash, it would return yes for `"  123   "` for instance. You wouldn't want to use that approach in ksh where it would not only work but also be a command injection vulnerability.

Comment: The entire matter of testing with "[[" vs "[", and the subtle differences therein which can often be lost to memory after reading up on the matter after only a few months, is precisely demonstrated in this answer. Therefore, I consider any type of pattern that is not reliable in any type of shell to be a "bad". As a result, I tend to make all code within a script use only one or the other type of test (i.e. if using bash, every test should be "[[" and would be considered "bad" if ever using "[" anywhere. Likewise for bourne shell, you can only use "[" and this type of test would be OK there)

Answer (score 12):

A POSIX and portable solution is:

```
read scale
if     [ -z "${scale##*[!0-9]*}" ]; 
then   echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

Comment: By far the best answer yet too many people don't use parameter expansion. This works on arrays too, incl $@: params=("${@##*[!0-9]*}") -- Keep all positional arguments, but only use numbers - anything else will be converted to null string which conveniently evaluates to 0 in arithmetic evaluations (my use case - function parameter is a list of integers, unset or null should default to 0 but caller sets variable name when unset).

Comment: getting this to work for all integers, not just non-negative, is trickier because of edge cases like `scale=1-2`. how to handle such a case depends on the application.

Answer (score 9):

For unsigned integers I use:

```
read -r scale
[ -z "${scale//[0-9]}" ] && [ -n "$scale" ] || echo "Sorry integers only"
```

Tests:

```
$ ./test.sh
7
$ ./test.sh
   777
$ ./test.sh
a
Sorry integers only
$ ./test.sh
""
Sorry integers only
$ ./test.sh

Sorry integers only
```

Comment: I like that one as it is made with builtins, fast, and seems quite posix... I tried on an old shell (bash 2.0.5) and it works perfectly.

Comment: What about spaces inside the argument? Like *” 086   “*.

Comment: @0andriy See the second test.

Answer (score 5):

```
( scale=${scale##*[!0-9]*}
: ${scale:?input must be an integer}
) || exit
```

That does the check and outputs your error.

Comment: `OPTIND` is good here, too. just saiyan.

Comment: By far the best answer yet too many people don't use parameter expansion. This works on arrays too, incl `$@`: `params=("${@##*[!0-9]*}")` -- Keep all positional arguments, but only use numbers - anything else will be converted to null string which conveniently evaluates to 0 in arithmetic evaluations (my use case - function parameter is a list of integers, unset or null should default to 0 but caller sets variable name when unset).

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
case $1 in
  ("" | *[!0123456789]*)
    echo >&2 Sorry, decimal integer only
    exit 1
esac
```

Do not use `[0-9]` which often matches a lot more than `[0123456789]` (especially with `bash` globs, YMMV for bash's `[[ =~ ]]` operator which uses the system regexps where `[0-9]` may or may not match more than `0123456789` depending on the system and locale).

More on that at [what is the meaning of this shell script function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616151)

Note that you may also want to reject numbers like `08` or `09` which some tools (including bash arithmetic operators) reject as invalid octal numbers.

Comment: "Do not use [0-9] which often matches a lot more" -- in which shell? Why? Where did you see this behavior in the wild?

Comment: @josch, have you followed the "more on that..." link? I've covered that on many Q&As and comments here and elsewhere. See also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html for bash

Comment: Thank you, that was a very educative read! I've adjusted my answer accordingly and will go through my own shell scripts fixing these instances.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use the [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) inside `[[...]]`:

```bsh
scale=4
[[ $scale == +([[:digit:]]) ]] || echo "Sorry integers only"
# ==> no output
```

```bsh
scale=4.0
[[ $scale == +([[:digit:]]) ]] || echo "Sorry integers only"
# ==> Sorry integers only
```

Answer (score 0):

For X greater than 0 I use

```
[ 0$X -gt 0 2>/dev/null ] && echo "is number" || echo "is string"
```

this gives no error if X is empty

Comment: That's not only wrong, but also a command injection vulnerability in bash and a few other shells. Try for instance with `X='x -o -v xx[$(reboot)1] -o 1'` in bash (gives true and reboots).

Answer (score 0):

## Less convoluted

The negation is now in the regular expression instead of the test condition.

```bash
if [[ $scale =~ [^0-9] ]]
    then
        echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

Explanation:

- `=~` binary operator where the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3))
- `[^0-9]` matches a single character not present in the list 0-9.

Comment: Of course, a negative sign breaks the idea.

Comment: That fails to filter out empty values or values that contain non-characters. On some systems and locales `[0-9]` matches more than the 0123456789 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following is POSIX compliant, so it will work in other shells than bash as well. Just checking `-z "${scale##*[!0-9]*}"` as suggested by another answer here does not take into account that strings starting with zero (except for zero itself) or empty strings are also not valid base-10 integers.

```
case "$scale" in *[!0123456789]*|0?*|"")
    echo "Sorry integers only";;
esac
```

We need to spell out all valid digits because using a range like `0-9` matches on any character (or possibly multi-character collation element) that sorts in between 0 and 9. Thanks to @stéphane-chazelas for this insight. More about that here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html

If negative integers are valid in your use case, you can use:

```
case "$scale" in *[!0123456789-]*|-|?*-*|0?*|-0|"")
    echo "Sorry integers only";;
esac
```