How to make bc handle explicitly positive numbers? Or what alternative calculator can be used with such support?
Consider the following:
$ echo "-1" | bc
-1

$ echo "(1)" | bc
1

$ echo "+1" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Minus sign and round braces are handled correctly but when explicit plus sign is specified bc falls with error. Is it possible to make it treat explicitly positive numbers just as normal positive numbers?
I want to be able to calculate constructions like:

+1++2 (result must be 3)

Even simple Ubuntu calculator can do such operations:

It is strange that bc can't. Seems like a bug.
As a workaround sed can be used to preprocess the input for bc, or perhaps bc has some specific config for this? Or may be there is some alternative to bc for that?

Update
I've sent request to bc's support team to consider to fix this bug.
Comments from Kusalananda:

bc is a POSIX utility, and any implementation of the utility
therefore should follow the POSIX specification. This specification
contains a grammar which does not include the unary plus operation. If
GNU implements a unary plus in their implementation of bc, they
would need to ensure that all existing code that uses bc still
performs as before and that any future code that uses bc performs as
a reader of the standard would expect.
Also note that -1--2 is an error, so you seem to additionally
propose a change in the precedence of the increment and decrement
operators, right?

My comment:

I think that bc should be able to perform simple calculations like
simple calculator can do. If support team adds to bc at least
ability to handle cases with digits like -1--2 (with result 1) and
+1++2 (with result 3) (only unary plus operation for digits, and not falling with error while trying to execute increment / decrement
operations on digits which all the same are not supported by now) in my understanding it will
not anyhow impact existing or future POSIX-compliant code.


What you call "explicit plus" is ordinarily called "the unary plus operator".  bc does to my knowledge not have the unary plus operator.

Many languages have both a unary + and ++ unary post-increment and pre-increment operators where that +1++2 would cause an error as that  would attempt to increment something that is not a variable. bc has increment but not unary +. So in terms of alternative to bc, are you looking for some tool or language that can do arbitrary precision arithmetic like bc, but support unary + and not increment operators? What's the use case? What do you need that for?

Try awk - much more convenient for proper math.

@user9101329 You may want to try awk 'BEGIN { print +1++2 }'.  Most languages that support both unary plus and increment operators wouldn't be able to handle that (awk handles it if you insert spaces), and that's the specific string they want to evaluate to +3.

@StéphaneChazelas use case: is to parse user input to define time period in convenient short way and to convert it to seconds. For example, 1h30m (d for days, h for hours, m for minutes, s for seconds) should be calculated as 5400 seconds (13600+3060). Other examples of input: 1d10s, 59s, 100m. Also I want to support cases with time correction by minus operation like: 1h-30s or 1d-10m. Like here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509724/585416 . I'm using now sed and bc to support this. I accidentally noticed that bc does not support 1--1, +1++1 operations.

@StéphaneChazelas I added screenshot of the simple calculator to the question. It seems strange that bc can't do the same. Seems to bug. Probably I should to consider using $(( )). This is echo $(( (2  --1) ++ 1 )) working as expected (result is 4).

Try this:
expr='+1++2'
echo "0+ $expr" | sed 's/+ *+ */+/g' | bc

You can use a shell like bash directly but it's a little cumbersome and possibly not as robust:
expr='+1++2'
_tmp="0+ $expr"
_tmp="${_tmp// /}"
echo "${_tmp//++/+}" | bc

The principle for both is the same. We prefix 0+ to the whole thing which, given we're about to collapse multiple + signs, allows us to work with 1+2 or +1+2 (the second temporarily resulting in 0++1+2). We then strip consecutive sequences of {+ and space} to a single +.

This is expression with support for both plus and minus signs: expr=" + 1 + + 1 - - 1 - + 1 + - 1 "; echo "0+ $expr" | sed 's/+ *+ */+/g;s/- *- */+/g;s/- *+ */-/g' | bc (result as expected 1). + - case is already supported by bc: echo " 1 + - 1 " | bc returns correct 0 result.

@ilkkachu right, expr=" + 1 + + 1 - - 1 - + 1 + - 1 "; echo "0+ $expr" | sed 's/\([-+]\) *+ */\1/g' | bc is more short equivalent that gives the same correct 1 result.

@ilkkachu This turned out to be not enough. Also needs to support separate case for --. echo "1--1 " | bc that bc tries to handle as decrement and falls with error. Full fixed expression: expr=" +1++1-+1--1+-1-1 + 1 + + 1 - + 1 - - 1 + - 1 -1 "; echo "0+ $expr" | sed 's/\([-+]\) *+ */\1/g;s/--/+/g' | bc

As an alternative to bc simple calculations can be done with built-in bash calculator — Arithmetic Expansion $((expression)):
expr="  +1++1-+1--1+-1-1 + 1 + + 1 - + 1 - - 1 + - 1 -1 "; echo $((expr))  # 0

Related article: How to Calculate in Bash [3 Practical Examples]

bc by now does not support unary plus operation for digits. Also it considers ++ and -- operations as increment and decrement though they are not supported for digits.
This is for cases for both plus and minus signs (adding unary plus operation support, fixing increment and decrement related errors):
echo "  +1++1-+1--1+-1-1 + 1 + + 1 - + 1 - - 1 + - 1 -1 " | sed 's/\([-+]\) *+ */\1/g;s/--/+/g;s/^ *+//' | bc  # 0

Specially needs to handle the following cases:
echo "+1" | bc  # error, bc does not support unary plus operation
echo "1+ +1" | bc  # error, bc does not support unary plus operation
echo "1- +1" | bc  # error, bc does not support unary plus operation
echo "2--1 " | bc  # error, bc tries to decrement 1
echo "2++1 " | bc  # error, bc tries to increment 1

sed preprocessing description:

s/\([-+]\) *+ */\1/g - collapses all occurrences of - + (with any amount of spaces between them) to -; + + to +
s/--/+/g - replaces -- to +
s/^ *+// - removes leading + (if any)

Cases with + - and - - are already supported by bc:
echo " - - 1 - - 1 " | bc  # 2
echo " 1 + - 1 " | bc  # 0

